# Reverse Proxy Apche2.4 how to enable google authentication

Tags: apache, google-app-engine, reverse-proxy, google-authentication

I'm trying to enable google authentication on my Apache 2.4 reverse proxy installed on CentOS7.
I installed **mod_auth_openidc**
I created **OAuth 2.0 Client IDs** on GSUITE console

This is my **/etc/httpd/conf/http.conf**:

```
<VirtualHost mtest.mydomain.com:80>    
  ServerName mtest.mydomain.com
  OIDCProviderMetadataURL https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration    
  OIDCClientID xxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com
  OIDCClientSecret xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  OIDCRedirectURI https://mtest.mydomain.com/    
  OIDCScope "profile openid"    
  OIDCCryptoPassphrase example@3003    
  OIDCCookiePath /    
  OIDCAuthNHeader X-Forwarded-User    
  OIDCRemoteUserClaim sub    
  OIDCClaimPrefix example_

<Location />
  AuthType openid-connect
  Require valid-user    
</Location>

 Redirect / https://mtest.mydomain.com/  

</VirtualHost> <VirtualHost mtest.mydomain.com:443>   
  ServerName mtest.mydomain.com   
  SSLEngine on   
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/ssl/mydomain.com.crt   
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/ssl/mydomain.com.key   
  SSLCACertificateFile /etc/httpd/ssl/gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt   
</VirtualHost>
```

But when I digit the url: http://mtest.mydomain.com I didn't rediret to google authentication page.

Where is my error?

Answer (score 0):

I solved in this way:

```
ProxyRequests off

<Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from all 
</Proxy> ProxyTimeout 300

<VirtualHost test.mydomain.com:80>    
   ServerName test.mydomain.com    
   Redirect / https://test.mydomain.com/ 
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost test.mydomain.com:443>
        ServerName test.mydomain.com
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/ssl/mydomain.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/ssl/mydomain.key
        SSLCACertificateFile /etc/httpd/ssl/gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt


OIDCProviderMetadataURL https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration
OIDCClientID xxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com   
OIDCClientSecret xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx   
OIDCRedirectURI https://test.mydomain.com/home.html   
OIDCScope "profile openid"   
OIDCCryptoPassphrase example@3003   
OIDCCookiePath /   
OIDCAuthNHeader X-Forwarded-User   
OIDCRemoteUserClaim sub   
OIDCClaimPrefix example_
<Location />   
    AuthType openid-connect   
    Require valid-user </Location>

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.1/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.1/ 
</VirtualHost>
```